# Changing PATH based on currenty directory

Tags: node.js, bash

I am working on a project that requires a user version of `Node.js`. I already have it installed with root privileges, and I would like to keep that, so my solution was to install a new version as user using the direct [download](https://nodejs.org/en/). With this in mind, I would like to make it so that when I make calls to Node from within my working project directory it uses the user version, and otherwise it defaults to the root version.

So, there are really 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to have different PATH variables depending on where in your directory structure you are?
2. Is this a good way of approaching this problem or is there a better way to manage versions of Node? (without too much overhead)

Comment: If you want to run a specific version of node, located in a specific place, why not just use the full path when running it rather than finding it via a path environment variable.

Comment: So that would work and is what I’ve been doing for the time being, but I am curious if what I described above is possible and if there’s a better approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate what you are asking by putting a relative path in your `PATH`;

```
PATH=./localnode:$PATH
```

Now if `./localnode/Node.js` exists in the current directory, it will take precedence over the system-wide `Node.js`

I would not particularly recommend this approach. A better or at least less peculiar approach is to run a separate shell with a different `PATH` (or an overriding function or alias) for the duration you want to override the system version. This also decouples this preference from changing your working directory, which generally should not have side effects like this.